# Disabling android built-in launcher

Tags: cookies

Can I ask If what will be the effects if I will Disable my Built-in android launcher and replace with the launcher that I have downloaded??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't show again unless you enable it. It won't cause any critical problems if you disable it.

Answer (score 1):

A smartphone is capable of performing several functions using a single device. That includes calls, messages, photo, video, internet, social media etc. So, if a manufacturer releases a phone, it should have these default features. That means, after device power on you can see phone app for call utility, camera app for photo, video capture, default keyboard for typing words. If anyone is missing, it would affect device functionality. Likewise, all applications arrangement/displaying  app is called **launcher**. These are the basic apps required for functioning and they are called **system apps**.

Android also allows you to install other apps that provides similar functions as I have mentioned above. They are called **user apps**.

For example, your device comes up with launcher app, and you can install Nova launcher app from play store. When such similar apps installed, you need to set a default app for use. to do that, go to Settings->Apps->Default apps->home app. set the one you required. It will also asks you to set default launcher while pressing home button after installation.

- system apps has options in settings: DISABLE and FORCE STOP
- user apps has options in settings :UNINSTALL and FORCE STOP

  - DISABLE is used disable app function. App icon will be removed from launcher. it will not affect other apps. Also, you cannot disable every system app.
  - FORCESTOP to stop currently running app
  - UNINSTALL remove app from device.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you don't uninstall it, you should be good:

- if you need to factory-reset the device, the launcher would be enabled again automatically. If you'd delete the app, you wouldn't have a launcher after a factory-reset and thus "sit in the dark" – and it would be quite tricky for a normal user to get out of that nasty situation.
- the launcher you've installed should take over from the one that came with the device. If you're satisfied with that, there's no need to keep the pre-installed launcher enabled.
- just make sure you do it in the opposite order as your question mentions it: first install the new launcher, then disable the pre-installed one :)